# Target Windows, Mac, Linux etc

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just a quick question.

Is there any way I can target a specific OS?

For example:

```
<!--[if]>
<![endif]-->
```

To set a certain stylesheet, for windows based users would be my ideal.

Let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OS-Specific CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774009/os-specific-css)

Comment: OP, the link @MaciejLach gave may be what you are looking for. the example on the selected answer's link correctly identified my OS and browser (linux,firefox)

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible, it's not a recommended approach. Feature detection is considered a better way of handling problems like this. Modernizr.js is one of the more popular client-side libraries that help solve this problem.

Comment: Why is it not a recommended approach?

Comment: There are a lot of OS/browser combinations to check for and you need to keep track of which ones support which features. Even if you cover them all by that approach, you need to keep up maintenance to handle any new combinations.

Comment: @yazan Here's a [link with more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to determine the user agent. (the `navigator.userAgent` property)

The user-agent has information about the client OS.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
```

Determine the OS, then dynamically append `<link/>` tags to the head section before page load

Comment: But that assumes that the client is being honest. It wouldn't be too hard to mess with the user-agent